# Can't dispose JFrame inside Thread

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a class that extends Thread and inside this class I have a JFrame. I need to dispose this JFrame without finalizing the system, like we do with `System.exit(0)`.

When I create and initialize the frame, it has a name like "frame0" but then, when I call it's name on the ActionListener, it shows "frame1", even if the JFrame class is final or static.

```
public class RegisterExercise extends Thread {

private final JFrame frame;
private JButton btnSave;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JButton btnCancel;
private JTextField txtName;
private JTextField txtEasyName;
private JTextField txtDescription;
private JTextField txtMachineName;
private JLabel lblName;
private JLabel lblEasyName;
private JLabel lblDescription;
private JLabel lblMachineName;

public RegisterExercise() {
    frame = new JFrame("Register an exercise");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(e -> {
        System.out.println("Frame:" + frame.getName());
        frame.dispose();
    });
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
             UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    initializeFrame(frame);
    super.run();
}

private void initializeFrame(JFrame frame) {
    frame.setContentPane(new RegisterExercise().mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("This is frame:" + frame.getName());
}
}
```

This class is called from another Thread that I created, I'll share here the class that calls this Thread class

```
public class Menu extends Thread {

private JButton btnExit;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JButton btnRegisterExercise;
private JTable menuTable;
private JLabel lblVersion;

// JFrames

private RegisterExercise registerExercise;

public Menu() {

    // Exit Button
    btnExit.addActionListener(e -> {
        int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want do leave?", "Leaving", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    // Register Exercise Button
    btnRegisterExercise.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (registerExercise == null) {
                registerExercise = new RegisterExercise();
                registerExercise.start();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
             UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Move Gym");
    frame.setContentPane(new Menu().mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    super.run();
}
}
```

Comment: Don't - Swing is not thread safe and you should be trying to create new instances of UI components outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  I can't see how the code you've posted would even run without generating a `NullPointerException` - consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but you definitely should NOT be extending Thread to create a JFrame. Swing components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. The tutorial contains many basic examples to get you started.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't ever extend Thread, except in very unusual circumstances. This isn't one of those.

Comment: Thanks guys! I learned this way a LONG time ago, about 5 years now, and recently needed to use Swing again and I had no idea how I'd do it back in the days! Now I know I was doing it wrong! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mad Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) said:
Don't - Swing is not thread safe and you should be trying to create new instances of UI components outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. I can't see how the code you've posted would even run without generating a NullPointerException - consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)